# Java ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(path) return null when resource is inside nested jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-io

My springboot project (project A) has dependency to library (library B) which is jar file (it's also my project, but source code is not present during compilation project A). Inside jar I have directory dir1 with one file file2.

Project structure:

```
- project A
-- src/main/java/com/test/ResourcesUtils.java
-- src/main/resources/dir1/file1

- library B
-- src/main/resources/dir1/file2
```

When I try to get resource from project A everything works fine for example:

```
InputStream is1 = ResourcesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dir1\\file1);
InputStream is2 = ResourcesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dir1/file1);
```

Both (is1, is2) are not null.

When I try to get resource from library B using the same method it does not work

```
InputStream is1 = ResourcesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dir1\\file2);
InputStream is2 = ResourcesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dir1/file2);
```

Variable is1 is null, is2 is not null.

Am I doing something wrong? Why it works different for resource from main jar than from dependent jar?

I can't just switch to second version (with '/', because I'm not controlling string which is passed to getResourceAsStream)

```
public static boolean existsInResource(Path path) {

try (InputStream is = ResourcesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path.toString())) {
      return is != null;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
      // handle exception
    }
  }
```

Comment: In code I have that works, a leading slash is used on the path.  Problems like this are always that you don't have the path quite right.  I think you want `/main/resources/dir1/file1`.

Comment: Path is ok, it works with '/' but does not work with '\' as path separator. In library jar dir1 is on root path, so I don't need to add '/main/resources...' etc.

Comment: The API is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) to use `/` as the separator, not ``\``. You mention you can't just switch to using the former because "I'm not controlling string which is passed to getResourceAsStream". But I assume you are allowed to process the string before passing it as an argument, no? Because if you can, then one option is to do `path = path.replace('\\', '/')` to change the back slashes to forward slashes.

Comment: Yes I can, but I thought that it should work also with '\'. Thank you for your answers and reffering to the documentation. You saved my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referring to `file1,` it is a physical file in your application, and I assume that you run your code on Windows. The file `file1` is in the Windows file system.

When referring to `file2`, it is inside a JAR file. That is not a windows file system, it is a JAR file.

Unless you know that the file is a physical file, it is safer to use the forward slash. The `\` is a residue from the old 32-bit windows before Windows NT. Windows NT inside (I am not sure if I remember it correctly) uses `/`, and the command processor only uses the `\`.

Comment: You are, of course, correct regarding why using ``\`` breaks once packaged in a JAR file. But that deals with implementation details. There is a more straightforward reason to **always** use `/`: _Because the API is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) as using `/` for the separator._